# Modals With 4 or More Close (X) Span On Click AREN'T Closing / FIXED Template With FIXED Modals

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I add 4 + Span On Close JS lines to my modals software, the close button Stops closing All of the modals.  How can I Fix that?

Also, when I Add Fixed Header / Fixed Footer modals to my Fixed Header template, the modals the modals go inside the site template, with the modals headers Not showing, and the template showing in the background when scrolling.  How can I get the modals to Cover the whole fixed header template?

```js
// Open A Modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

// Get A Button That Opens A Modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-open-buttons");

// Get A <span> Element That Closes A Modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When User Clicks On A Modal Open Button, Open A Modal.  Must Start With 0, And Count Up 
btn[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "block";
};

btn[1].onclick = function() {
    modal[1].style.display = "block";
};

btn[2].onclick = function() {
    modal[2].style.display = "block";
};

btn[3].onclick = function() {
    modal[3].style.display = "block";
};

btn[4].onclick = function() {
    modal[4].style.display = "block";
};

btn[5].onclick = function() {
    modal[5].style.display = "block";
};

btn[6].onclick = function() {
    modal[6].style.display = "block";
};

btn[7].onclick = function() {
    modal[7].style.display = "block";
};

btn[8].onclick = function() {
    modal[8].style.display = "block";
};

btn[9].onclick = function() {
    modal[9].style.display = "block";
};

// When Users Click On A Modal Close Button <span> (x), Close A Modal.  Must Start With 0, And Count Up
span[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "none";
};

span[1].onclick = function() {
    modal[1].style.display = "none";
};

span[2].onclick = function() {
    modal[2].style.display = "none";
};

span[3].onclick = function() {
    modal[3].style.display = "none";
};

span[4].onclick = function() {
    modal[4].style.display = "none";
};

span[5].onclick = function() {
    modal[5].style.display = "none";
};

span[6].onclick = function() {
    modal[6].style.display = "none";
};

span[7].onclick = function() {
    modal[7].style.display = "none";
};

span[8].onclick = function() {
    modal[8].style.display = "none";
};

span[9].onclick = function() {
    modal[9].style.display = "none";
};

// When Users Click Anywhere Outside of a Modal, Close That Modal
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

```css
/* The Modal (Background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden By Default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay In Place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit On Top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full Width */
    height: 100%; /* Full Height */
    overflow: scroll; /* Enable Scroll If Feeded */
}


/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 90px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -moz-animation-name: animatetop;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

.modal-open-buttons {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #4169E1;
  border-color: #663399;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* The Close Button */
.modal-header .close {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #663399;
}

.modal-header .close:hover,
.modal-header .close:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.modal-header {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #C0C0C0;
  color: #4169E1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
}

.modal-header .left-column {
  float: left;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #C0C0C0;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.modal-header .right-column {
  float: right;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #C0C0C0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.modal-body {
    /* DON'T USE WIDTH FOR THE MODAL BODY!*/
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
   color: #663399;
   padding-right: 5px;
   padding-left: 5px;
}

.modal-footer {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background: #663399;
  color: #FFF;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
}

/* iFrame On SMALL Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  
.modal-video-iframe  {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-video-iframe  iframe {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 65px;
    border: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 65% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
  }
}

/* iFrame On BIG Screens */

.modal-video-iframe  {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.modal-video-iframe  iframe {
    position: absolute;
    border: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

.IE-NO-iFrame-Videos {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #4169E1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <!-- The Above 3 Meta Tags MUST Come First In The Head; Any Other Head Content MUST Come AFTER These Tags -->
    
<Title>MODALS</Title>

</head>

<body>
    
<br><br>

<!-- Trigger / Open A Modal -->
<button class="modal-open-buttons">Open A<br>Text Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal-01" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal Content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
      
    <div class="modal-header">
      
  <div class="columns left-column">
      
    <p>THIS IS A TEXT MODAL HEADER</p>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="columns right-column">
      
    <span class="close">(X)</span>
      
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal-body">
        
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal-footer">
        
      <h3>MODAL FOOTER</h3>
      
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<br><br>

<!-- Trigger / Open A Modal -->
<button class="modal-open-buttons">Open A<br>Video Modal</button>

<p class="IE-NO-iFrame-Videos">iFRAME VIDEOS AREN'T SUPPORTED ON IE!</p>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal-02" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal Content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
      
    <div class="modal-header">
      
  <div class="columns left-column">
      
    <p>THIS IS A VIDEO MODAL HEADER</p>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="columns right-column">
      
    <span class="close">(X)</span>
      
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
   <div class="modal-body">
      
      <div class="modal-video-iframe">
      
      <!--<iframe src="https://NewTube.app/embed/ATrboWO" allowfullscreen></iframe>-->
      
      <iframe src="https://tv.gab.com/channel/richardgage33/embed/what-can-a-cdi-explosives-loader-61ebff750f7a80b265bbd5f6" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      
      </div>
      
      </div>
    
    <div class="modal-footer">
        
      <h3>MODAL FOOTER</h3>
      
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<br><br>

<!-- Trigger / Open A Modal -->
<button class="modal-open-buttons">Open A<br>Video Modal</button>

<p class="IE-NO-iFrame-Videos">iFRAME VIDEOS AREN'T SUPPORTED ON IE!</p>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal-03" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal Content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
      
    <div class="modal-header">
      
  <div class="columns left-column">
      
    <p>THIS IS A VIDEO MODAL HEADER</p>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="columns right-column">
      
    <span class="close">(X)</span>
      
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
   <div class="modal-body">
       
      <div class="modal-video-iframe">
      
      <!--<iframe src="https://NewTube.app/embed/ATrboWO" allowfullscreen></iframe>-->
      
      <iframe src="https://tv.gab.com/channel/richardgage33/embed/what-can-a-cdi-explosives-loader-61ebff750f7a80b265bbd5f6" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      
      </div>
      
      </div>
    
    <div class="modal-footer">
        
      <h3>MODAL FOOTER</h3>
      
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for your first question, are you saying that `window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
};` is not working as you expected?

Comment: Yes James.  Once I add a 4th and beyond Span On Close script, the modals stop closing.

Comment: span[3].onclick = function() {
    modal[3].style.display = "none";
};

Comment: Post an answer, check if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

**The most obvious problem that your code doesn't work is your only has 9 `modal`, you only have three.**

Also, your code is currently displaying `typeerror`. The problem is `modal` has 9 elements and in your `window.onclick`, you directly  use modal which is incorrect.

You have to specify each element.

In my code below, you could use  `forEach` loop to loop over it.

Also, I specify all your other JS code using `forEach` which is much clearer and easier.

```js
// Open A Modal
var modal = [...document.getElementsByClassName('modal')];

// Get A Button That Opens A Modal
var btn = [...document.getElementsByClassName("modal-open-buttons")];

// Get A <span> Element That Closes A Modal
var span = [...document.getElementsByClassName("close")];

// When User Clicks On A Modal Open Button, Open A Modal.  Must Start With 0, And Count Up 
btn.forEach((button,i)=>{
button.addEventListener('click',()=>modal[i].style.display= 'block')
})
span.forEach((s,i) =>{
s.addEventListener('click',()=>modal[i].style.display = "none");
})

window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
modal.forEach(item=>{
if (event.target == item) 
 item.style.display = "none";
})
});
```

```css
/* The Modal (Background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden By Default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay In Place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit On Top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full Width */
    height: 100%; /* Full Height */
    overflow: scroll; /* Enable Scroll If Feeded */
}


/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 90px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -moz-animation-name: animatetop;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

.modal-open-buttons {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #4169E1;
  border-color: #663399;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* The Close Button */
.modal-header .close {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #663399;
}

.modal-header .close:hover,
.modal-header .close:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.modal-header {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #C0C0C0;
  color: #4169E1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
}

.modal-header .left-column {
  float: left;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #C0C0C0;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.modal-header .right-column {
  float: right;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #C0C0C0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.modal-body {
    /* DON'T USE WIDTH FOR THE MODAL BODY!*/
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
   color: #663399;
   padding-right: 5px;
   padding-left: 5px;
}

.modal-footer {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background: #663399;
  color: #FFF;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
}

/* iFrame On SMALL Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  
.modal-video-iframe  {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-video-iframe  iframe {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 65px;
    border: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 65% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
  }
}

/* iFrame On BIG Screens */

.modal-video-iframe  {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.modal-video-iframe  iframe {
    position: absolute;
    border: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

.IE-NO-iFrame-Videos {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #4169E1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <!-- The Above 3 Meta Tags MUST Come First In The Head; Any Other Head Content MUST Come AFTER These Tags -->
    
<Title>MODALS</Title>

</head>

<body>
    
<br><br>

<!-- Trigger / Open A Modal -->
<button class="modal-open-buttons">Open A<br>Text Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal-01" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal Content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
      
    <div class="modal-header">
      
  <div class="columns left-column">
      
    <p>THIS IS A TEXT MODAL HEADER</p>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="columns right-column">
      
    <span class="close">(X)</span>
      
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal-body">
        
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
      <p>THIS IS A DEMO OF A SCROLLING MODAL WITH A FIXED HEADER, AND A FIXED FOOTER!  &nbsp; MODALS CAN BE USED FOR TEXT, IMAGES, VIDEOS, FORMS, ETC.!</p>
      
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal-footer">
        
      <h3>MODAL FOOTER</h3>
      
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<br><br>

<!-- Trigger / Open A Modal -->
<button class="modal-open-buttons">Open A<br>Video Modal</button>

<p class="IE-NO-iFrame-Videos">iFRAME VIDEOS AREN'T SUPPORTED ON IE!</p>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal-02" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal Content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
      
    <div class="modal-header">
      
  <div class="columns left-column">
      
    <p>THIS IS A VIDEO MODAL HEADER</p>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="columns right-column">
      
    <span class="close">(X)</span>
      
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
   <div class="modal-body">
      
      <div class="modal-video-iframe">
      
      <!--<iframe src="https://NewTube.app/embed/ATrboWO" allowfullscreen></iframe>-->
      
      <iframe src="https://tv.gab.com/channel/richardgage33/embed/what-can-a-cdi-explosives-loader-61ebff750f7a80b265bbd5f6" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      
      </div>
      
      </div>
    
    <div class="modal-footer">
        
      <h3>MODAL FOOTER</h3>
      
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<br><br>

<!-- Trigger / Open A Modal -->
<button class="modal-open-buttons">Open A<br>Video Modal</button>

<p class="IE-NO-iFrame-Videos">iFRAME VIDEOS AREN'T SUPPORTED ON IE!</p>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal-03" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal Content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
      
    <div class="modal-header">
      
  <div class="columns left-column">
      
    <p>THIS IS A VIDEO MODAL HEADER</p>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="columns right-column">
      
    <span class="close">(X)</span>
      
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
   <div class="modal-body">
       
      <div class="modal-video-iframe">
      
      <!--<iframe src="https://NewTube.app/embed/ATrboWO" allowfullscreen></iframe>-->
      
      <iframe src="https://tv.gab.com/channel/richardgage33/embed/what-can-a-cdi-explosives-loader-61ebff750f7a80b265bbd5f6" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      
      </div>
      
      </div>
    
    <div class="modal-footer">
        
      <h3>MODAL FOOTER</h3>
      
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks James!  I Changed the JS to the JS that you suggested, and that's Much Better!  Now the Other issue, and I'll be on my way!  :--)

Comment: @TipTop, I would be glad to help, but I don;t understand your second issue you describe in the problem, could you be more descriptive

Comment: The modals show the Fixed Footer of the modals.  However, the Fixed Header of the modals Isn't showing.  The Fixed Header of the site template shows instead.  Also, I can see sections of the site template in the background, when scrolling via the modals.  :--)

Comment: @TipTop, I am really willing to help, but it is too hard for me to guess and hardstand the error, will it be better that you could put some images  about the error in your question?

Comment: @TipTop, I have understand the problem you can see sections of the site template in the background, when scrolling via the modals, but how is the ` Header of the modals` not showing, it only shows up when yoh click the button?

Comment: The Fixed Header of the modals Never appears to show when using the site template.  I want the Whole modals to show Over the Template, with None of the Template showing.  :--)

Comment: @TipTop, your modal-header doesn't have content, it just group `THIS IS A VIDEO MODAL HEADER` and this does show when user click it:)

Comment: Click where it says Open A Text Modal on the site template.  Not on the Modals Template.  I did that on various phone, and computer browsers.  When doing that, it Doesn't show the Header of modals.  Also, on the Template, I Don't currently have any Video Modals.  :--)

Comment: Go to  https://SecureSimpleBooking.com, and Go to the Get Tickets section.  Then click on the Test Modal.... You'll get what I'm saying.  :--)

Comment: @TipTop， you may looking for code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, not stackoveflow. Also you should asking several questions on 1 question, this is considered not focused. You could consider accepting the answer if it solves one of questions

Comment: W3C says NO Errors in that template.  :--)

Comment: @Shawn Originally the code wasn't working. Unless it started working to conform with expectations now, it's not on-topic on CR. Footers/modals not showing is code that's not working.

Comment: @TipTop, The w3c only check if there is error in html structure, but what make your code doesn’t work is a obviously JavaScript. Anyways good luck:)

Comment: @Mast, sorry my misunderstanding about code review

Comment: I Temp Turned Off the Navbar JS File, and the Issue Remained.  I currently Don't have anything in the Main JS file.  :--)

Comment: I Tested these Modals on CodePen Templates.  The Same thing happens.  I simply need to learn how to get the Modals to Fully Cover any Fixed Header Template.  :--)